# Regex to allow only numbers, dashes and dots

Tags: regex

What should be the Regex to allow a string that contains only numbers (0-9) or dashes (-) or dots (.)?

And disallow when a string contains otherwise (like alphabets or other special characters not listed above).

Example:
Allowed

- 0
- 500-100-2.3.123

Disallowed

- abc123
- 500-a-c.def
- 100*

Comment: Also please specify what language are you using?

Comment: @MarounMaroun, isn't regex independent from programming language? By the way, I'm using c# if that helps. :)

Comment: @Boy It is. But sometimes the language provides a ready-to-use methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this:

```
^[0-9.-]*$
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for.
Thank you!

Comment: This regex allows an empty string too. To disallow empty string replace star with plus.